# Get innerText + alt if have img

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events, innertext

i have a span like

```
<span class="message">blablabla <img src="smileys/saute.gif" alt="SAUTE"></span>
```

i want to get the text + the alt of image if are there

I have tried :

```
let el = document.getElementById(".message");
console.log(el.innerText)
```

but it return just the text, i want text + alt of img (as if we copy paste with the mouse on a browser)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```js
const spanText = document.querySelector(".message").textContent;
const spanImgAlt = document.querySelector(".message img").getAttribute("alt");

console.log("<span> Text:", spanText);
console.log("<img> alt:", spanImgAlt);
```

```html
<span class="message">blablabla <img src="smileys/saute.gif" alt="SAUTE"></span>
```

---

If you want to check for the presence of the `span` and `img` tags before accessing their content, here's the code for it:

```js
const span = document.querySelector(".message");

if ( span ){

  console.log("<span> Text:", span.textContent);

  const spanImg = span.querySelector("img");

  if ( spanImg ){
    console.log("<img> alt:", spanImg.alt);
  }

}
```

```html
<span class="message">blablabla <img src="smileys/saute.gif" alt="SAUTE"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use `getElementById`. You want [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to use a CSS selector to pick up the element with the message class.
2. Then use `querySelector` again on that element to find the image, and log the `alt` attribute.

```js
const el = document.querySelector(".message");
const img = el.querySelector('img');
console.log(el.innerText, img.alt);
```

```html
<span class="message">blablabla <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="SAUTE" /></span>
```

Comment: indeed, by simplifying my code to post it here I forgot to change class to id :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :-

```html
<span class="message">blablabla <img width="50px"
  src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" ></span>
```

```js
let message = document.querySelector('.message').innerText
console.log(message)
let alt = document.querySelector('.message img').getAttribute('alt')
if(alt != null){
  console.log(alt)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the span element does not have any ID, it has a class so you can target it via querySelector:

`document.querySelector('.message')`
Note that querySelector returns the first element it finds, querySelectorAll returns an array of found elements.

Then you can use the element you found and go the the `firstElementChild` / or use `children[0]` (the index of the child).

You can even use:
`document.querySelector('.message > img')` to target the image.

```
const el = document.querySelector('.message');
cosnole.log("Inner text: ", el.innerText);
const img = el.firstElementChild;
console.log("Img alt: ", img.alt);
```